# Combine BytesX and BytesY to create BytesZ?

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32, solidity-0.5.x

I am working on a Solidity Smart Contract (^0.5.10) where I want to return an array of `Ratings` elements.

```
struct Ratings {
    address restaurant
    uint8 score
};
```

Since returning `Rating[]`, `string[]`, and `bytes[]` from functions is still experimental, I was attempting to compress the struct into a `byte22[]` and return that in a serialized format. But I don't know how to combine `byteX` objects into another `byteX` object.

I have 3 variables like so:

```
bytes20 address_string = BytesUtils.toBytes(restaurant.experience);
bytes1 separator = bytes1(";");
bytes1 rating = BytesUtils.toBytes(review.rating);
```

How can I combine them to create a `byte22`?

Comment: A typical solution is to just return two arrays: `returns (address[] restaurants, uint8[] scores)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can help your purpose.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract A {

    bytes private finalBytes;


    function setBytesCombined() external {
        bytes20 address_string = toBytes(msg.sender);

        bytes1 separator = bytes1(";");

        // Combining.......
        string memory combinedStringEmpty = new string(address_string.length + separator.length);

        bytes memory combinedBytes = bytes(combinedStringEmpty);

        uint iter = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i < address_string.length; i++) {
            combinedBytes[iter++] = address_string[i];
        }

        for (uint i = 0; i < separator.length; i++) {
            combinedBytes[iter++] = separator[i];
        }

        finalBytes = bytes(combinedBytes);
    }

    function getBytesCombined() public view returns(bytes memory) {
        return finalBytes;
    }

    function toBytes(address a) internal pure returns (bytes20 b) {
        return bytes20(uint160(a));
    }
}
```